# Detect which event Submits the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that I Submit by jQuery as well as when user clicks the Submit button:

Eg:-

**jQuery submit**

*on some event*

```
jQuery("#live_form").submit();
```

**Button click submit**

*on button click*

```
jQuery("#button1").click(function(){
  jQuery("#live_form").submit();
});
```

I need to execute a function(**say func1**) when the form is submitted by jQuery way and otherwise another function (**say func2**) when form submits on button click.

```
jQuery("#live_form").submit(function(){
  //some code
});
```

How can I distinguish between these submits without using global variables?

Comment: well that depends on markup can you post that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery("#button1").click(function(event){
  console.log("Form submit from "+event.target.nodeName);
  jQuery("#live_form").submit();
});

jQuery("#live_form").submit(function(event){
 console.log("Form submit from "+event.target.nodeName);
});
```

the first block returns `BUTTON` and second block return `FORM`

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Although it solves my issue, but I wonder how will I differentiate if there is more than one jQuery submit used in code (No button Involved and here `event.target.nodeName` gives FORM always).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
       var fromWhere = {};
        jQuery("#button1").click(function(){
          fromWhere = $(this);
          jQuery("#live_form").submit();
        });

        jQuery("#live_form").submit(function(){
         fromWhere = $(this);
        });
        console.log(fromWhere);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target.nodeName` property to identify from which its submitted.  Code here:

```
$("#yourform").submit(function(event){
if(event.target.nodeName=="BUTTON"){
 functionOne();
}else if(event.target.nodeName=="FORM"){
 functionTwo();
}
});
```